# VerticalDivider not appearing in Row

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

I tried to add a Vertical Divider in a row. The width of the divider is set but the divider doesn't appear. I also tried with the IntrinsicHeight Widget, it works for now. But it is advised not to use that so, in other threads. Is there a workaround

here's the code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:focus7/Configurations/styles.dart';
import 'package:focus7/Widgets/settings.dart';

class Profile extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final Shader textGradient =
        Styles.primaryGradient.createShader(Rect.fromLTWH(0.0, 0.0, 50, 50));

    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 40),
          child: Align(alignment: Alignment.centerRight, child: SettingsIcon()),
        ),
        SizedBox(height: 30),
        Align(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: CircleAvatar(
              radius: 60,
              backgroundColor: Colors.amber,
              backgroundImage: AssetImage("Assets/ninja_image_png.png"),
            )),
        SizedBox(height: 10),
        Text(
          "Bala Ganesh",
          style: Styles.titleWhiteTextStyle,
        ),
        SizedBox(height: 10),
        Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Column(
                children: <Widget>[
        Text(
          "LEVEL",
          style: Styles.normalWhiteTextStyle
              .copyWith(foreground: Paint()..shader = textGradient),
        ),
        SizedBox(height: 10),
        Text(
          "4",
          style: Styles.normalWhiteTextStyle,
        ),
                ],
              ),
              VerticalDivider(color: Styles.primaryWhite,thickness: 10,width: 20,),
              Column(
                children: <Widget>[
        Text(
          "POINTS",
          style: Styles.normalWhiteTextStyle
              .copyWith(foreground: Paint()..shader = textGradient),
        ),
        SizedBox(height: 10),
        Text(
          "250",
          style: Styles.normalWhiteTextStyle,
        ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

here's the output:

[image]

Comment: I don't have any problem with it.. please create reproducible code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap you row widget with **IntrinsicHeight** will solve your issue.

```
 IntrinsicHeight(
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(
                    "LEVEL",
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 10),
                  Text(
                    "4",
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              VerticalDivider(
                color: Colors.black,
                thickness: 10,
                width: 20,
              ),
              Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(
                    "POINTS",
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 10),
                  Text(
                    "250",
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The intrinsic height works but in the documentation, it was said that "Avoid using it where possible. In the worst case, this widget can result in a layout that is O(N²) in the depth of the tree." So, I asked if there was any other method to implement this vertical divider without intrinsic height

Comment: I think then you can simply use container and give width, height  and colour property which also work like divider.